# Meaning of “see combat”

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

> My own father saw combat on that frontier of freedom.

Does it mean his father experienced the combat? Or is he just a witness?

Comment: I think it could mean both

Comment: Or it could mean either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means he was actively involved in the conflict, as a soldier.

This expression is used to distinguish between soldiers who have "back office" jobs, for example working in planning or logistics, and those who are actually carrying a gun.

It doesn't imply that he actually killed anyone, though that is quite possible for a soldier who saw combat.

Examples:

> President Dwight D. Eisenhower never saw combat, but his role as a General and logistical planner was invaluable. On the other hand George H.W. Bush saw combat as a pilot, and John F. Kennedy commanded a torpedo boat.
>
> During World War 2, thousands of women served in the military in support roles, e.g. as nurses, but in Russia some saw combat.